# My Wifi usb stick drops connection after random amount of time

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, 20.04, lubuntu

I have some problems with my wifi usb stick on Lubuntu 20.04. It drops the connection after a random amount of time and it seems that it has its difficulties staying connected through usb.
It uses `rt2800usb`.

`modinfo -F parm rt2800usb` shows me the option of `nohwcrypt:Disable hardware enryption. (bool)`
Should I enable this option? And if yes, how to do it and is it safe?

I also have enabled usb modeswitch  now, because the stick seems to be in cd-rom mode while not working, but it does not help really well.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.